# selectItems from PrimeFaces simply won't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to a populate a selectItems from a query and It simply won't WORK. I've tried with List list, List list, Map<Long,String> list... None of then works... There's no error, the prime faces won't show the list. Simply as that.

```
      <p:selectOneMenu id="pessoa" value="#{matriculaController.pessoa}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma Pessoa" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems
          value="#{selectOneMenuView.pessoaLista}"
          var="pessoa"
          itemLabel="#{pessoa.nome}"
          itemValue="#"
        />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Controller:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Autowired
private List<Person> pessoaLista;

public void findAllPersons() {
    pessoaLista = matriculaService.carregarPessoas();
}
```

My query function is working, the `pessoaLista` is populated, the HTML doesn't break. It simply comes blank.

And I've copied from the PrimeFaces docs... ([docs](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml?jfwid=51eeb))

[image: selectOneMenu List]

Comment: Are you indeed implying that it works completely fine when you use a plain HTML element instead of `<f:selectItems>` like so `<p>#{selectOneMenuView.pessoaLista}</p>`? Or does it also fail the same way?

Comment: All items will get the same key? `itemValue="#"`

Comment: What does the picture represent? The tutorial or the component you created?

Answer (score -1):

Use `List<Person>` and add `itemValue="#{pessoa.id}"` to your `<f:selectItems>`

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="pessoa" 
                     value="#{matriculaController.pessoa}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma Pessoa" 
                      itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.pessoaLista}"
                       var="pessoa"
                       itemLabel="#{pessoa.nome}"
                       itemValue="#{pessoa.id}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```